# HTML page can't scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I took a invoice template from Internet and edited according to my requirments , but didnot modify any code in css file. Origin invoice can scroll down without any issue but my modified page could scroll this is the css part could any one help me :

```
/*
     CSS-Tricks Example
     by Chris Coyier
     http://css-tricks.com
*/

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, serif; }
#page-wrap { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }

textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table td, table th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#header { height: 15px; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0; background: #222; text-align: center; color: white; font: bold 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; text-decoration: uppercase; letter-spacing: 20px; padding: 8px 0px; }

#address { width: 250px; height: 150px; float: left; }
#customer { overflow: hidden; }

#logo { text-align: right; float: right; position: relative; margin-top: 25px; border: 1px solid #fff; max-width: 540px; max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
#logo:hover, #logo.edit { border: 1px solid #000; margin-top: 0px; max-height: 125px; }
#logoctr { display: none; }
#logo:hover #logoctr, #logo.edit #logoctr { display: block; text-align: right; line-height: 25px; background: #eee; padding: 0 5px; }
#logohelp { text-align: left; display: none; font-style: italic; padding: 10px 5px;}
#logohelp input { margin-bottom: 5px; }
.edit #logohelp { display: block; }
.edit #save-logo, .edit #cancel-logo { display: inline; }
.edit #image, #save-logo, #cancel-logo, .edit #change-logo, .edit #delete-logo { display: none; }
#customer-title { font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; float: left; }

#meta { margin-top: 1px; width: 300px; float: right; }
#meta td { text-align: right;  }
#meta td.meta-head { text-align: left; background: #eee; }
#meta td textarea { width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right; }

#items { clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee; }
#items textarea { width: 80px; height: 50px; }
#items tr.item-row td { border: 0; vertical-align: top; }
#items td.description { width: 300px; }
#items td.item-name { width: 175px; }
#items td.description textarea, #items td.item-name textarea { width: 100%; }
#items td.total-line { border-right: 0; text-align: right; }
#items td.total-value { border-left: 0; padding: 10px; }
#items td.total-value textarea { height: 20px; background: none; }
#items td.balance { background: #eee; }
#items td.blank { border: 0; }

#terms { text-align: center; margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
#terms h5 { text-transform: uppercase; font: 13px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 0 0 8px 0; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
#terms textarea { width: 100%; text-align: center;}

textarea:hover, textarea:focus, #items td.total-value textarea:hover, #items td.total-value textarea:focus, .delete:hover { background-color:#EEFF88; }

.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delete { display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; background: #EEEEEE; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 3px; border: 1px solid; top: -6px; left: -22px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: is there any problem for couldn't scroll?

Comment: Welcome, @user2988617. You'll have better success getting your question answered if you can explain what you have tried so far that isn't working. Be specific. See "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: `but didnot modify any code in css file` So why posting unmodified CSS file and not instead posting what you modified???

Comment: Please don't downwote, let's help him

Comment: please add the html code to. coz even embedded stylesheet can affect ur page

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for.. but, guessing that you are not able to see the scrollbar, I think i see a couple of `overflow: hidden`. Take that out if you need the scrollbar back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe delete

```
overflow:hidden
```

from the beginning of your CSS-section in:

```
textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
```

It does not really make sense to me but as you did not post anything else it's the only part that has to do with scrolling in your posted CSS.
Sometimes programming is crazy and maybe that works :D

In generell the CSS property

> overflow

is able to prevent the scrolling on HTML Elements. If you set it to

> overflow: hidden

you are no more able to scroll inside that element.